# Migrating JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 and RichFaces 3.3 to 4.3 and Seam 2.2 to 2.3 Servlet.service() Error

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x, seam2

I'm trying to migrate seam 2.2 to 2.3, richfaces 3.3 to 4.3 and jsf 1.2 to 2.1.
I've done migrating process but my richfaces a4j:commadlink is not working. Its not rendering.
I did update necessary code in richfaces 3.3 to 4.3.

JSF (part of page)

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/taglib"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org/"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" template="layout/template.xhtml"
xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext">
```

---

```
<ric:toolBar>
<rich:toolbarGroup location="right" styleClass="scToolbarLink">
                <a4j:commandLink value="#{messages['label.search']}"
                    render="resultTablePanel"
                    execute="@form"
                    action="{xxxx.refresh()}/>
<rich:toolBar/>
```

These are Errors:

```
16:26:47,421 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].    [/xxx].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-7) Servlet.service() for servlet  Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

   ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/bosCCB].[default]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-7) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

 (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-7) JBAS010152: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 0
```

It says null resource but there isn't null resource.

Comment: Which JSF implementation do you use? Which version? We've migrated from RF3.3->RF4.3, Seam2.2->Seam2.3 too but I didn't noticed same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is `<ric:toolBar>` typo or you have there **ric** instead of **rich** in your code?